# Adaptar Web.Config para .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, htaccess, web.config

preciso manter dois sites na mesma hospedagem (um que eu desenvolvi, vamos chamar de site 01) e outro que é um Wordpress criado pela antiga empresa que atendia o cliente (Chamamos de site 02).

A estrutura de diretórios está assim:

- /common (Meu novo site)
- /pt (Meu novo site)
- /en (Meu novo site)
- /es (Meu novo site)
- /site02 (Wordpress)
- .htaccess (Meu novo site)
- index.php (Meu novo site)
- web.config (Wordpress)

O web.config faz meu site parar de funcionar ao entrar em alguma página interna.
Ao remover o web.config e deixar o htaccess, quem para é o site02. Tentei mover o web.config para dentro do diretório /site02, mas mesmo assim não funcionou. Ele dá alguns erros de loop infinito.

Já não sei mais o que fazer.

**Meu HTACCESS da raiz:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(common|sistema|upload|tubosapolo)($|/) - [L]
    RewriteRule !\.(css|js|xml|bmp|swf|flv|ico|html|pdf|woff|ttf|svg|eot|zip|mp3|jpg|png|gif|jpeg|ai|eps|ico)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

O conteúdo de **web.config** da raiz:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/tubosapolo/index.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Tubos Apolo" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Se eu remover o meu htaccess, o site02 funciona. Mas minhas páginas internas do site01 vão todas para o 404 do site02. Isso que não entendo!

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: `web.config` e `.htaccess` juntos ? mas um site funciona com IIS e o outro com Apache ?

Comment: @Augusto eu também me surpreendi, e sim, os dois funcionam juntos sem problemas. Mas a idéia era deixar apenas um, no caso, somente o .htaccess, mas não estou sabendo como transcrever este webconfig para esse "idioma".

Comment: Este web.config está interferindo em todo o ambiente de hospedagem, e não sei dizer o porque. Gostaria que ele afetasse apenas o diretório /tubosapolo.

Comment: Na verdade o que acontece é que a porta de entrada esta sendo o IIS. Teste parar o IIS e fazer o .htacces funcionar com os 2